# Get id of an looped in html element

Tags: html, django, ajax

```
{% for product in products %}
...
         <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="{{product.id}}">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productQuantity" id="productQuantity" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" placeholder="1">
                 <div class="input-group-append">
                     <button type='button' name="addToCart" id="addToCart" value="+" class="btn btnother"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm" style="color: white;"></i></button>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </form>   
...
{% endfor %}
```

This is a simplified code!

So I have an e-commerce Django website. On the main page I represent cards of different products with possibility of adding them to cart.

Every time someone adds item to a cart, I want to only update cart image in header. So I want to use AJAX to pass `productId` and `productQuantity` to my `views.py`.

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').click(function() {

    var productId = $('#productId').val();
    var productQuantity = $('#productQuantity').val();

    if (Number.isInteger(Number(productQuantity))){
      productQuantity = productQuantity;
    } else {
      productQuantity = 1;
    }
  
    $.ajax({
      url: 'update',
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      data: { 'productId' : productId,
              'productQuantity' : productQuantity }
    });

  });
});
```

However, when I add to cart, the `productId` being printed is the same for all products. I think it is because after the `for loop` it stores only the last `productId`

What would be a way to get the id of every individual element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each `form` have a `productId`, you can specify the range when you get the value of `productId`,you can use below code to find `productId` only within current `form`:

```
var productId = $(this).find('#productId').val();
```